# Strange ln Login item

Tags: macos, unix, login-items

I was going through my login background tasks and saw the following:

[image]

Not sure why ln would have a startup task. As far as I know, that's just the link command from Unix. Clicking the info led me to the unix executable. Getting info indicated it was created on Oct 22, 2022 which would not make sense if this were the native unix file (unless there was an update).

Anyone have any ideas on what this might be?

Comment: This looks like macOS, not Unix. Not sure what you mean by the date thing. // It’s highly likely this is the result of an (programming) error in an installation process.

Comment: Looks like Docker can make `ln` tasks: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/452090 . For more information, you would need to add what the task is executing

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Looks like that's the answer –– thanks!